# How to break a loop in R after certain time?

Tags: r

I'm trying to optimize Schaffer function with Simulated Annealing and Steepest Descent methods. I'd like to add a termination criteria to a loop that would break the loop after let's say 5 seconds. Unfortunately I'm lost where i suppose to place such a condition in a more complicated loop like this:

```
currIter <- 0
finished <- FALSE
x_old <- x

while(finished == FALSE){
StartT <- Sys.time()
x_new <- lineSearch(f, x_old, x_old - a*numGradient(f, x_old, 10^-6), 10)
if(currIter <= maxIter & abs(f(x_new)-f(x_old))>e & f(x_new)<f(x_old)){
  x_old <- x_new
  result$x_opt  <- x_new
  result$f_opt  <- f(x_new)
  result$x_hist <- rbind(result$x_hist, x_new)
  result$f_hist <- rbind(result$f_hist, f(x_new))
  result$iter   <- currIter
  result$tEval   <- rbind(result$tEval, Sys.time() - StartT)
}else{
  finished <- TRUE
}
currIter <- currIter + 1
}
return(result)
}
```

So can I just place a condition like this?

```
while(sys.time() < 3)
```

Comment: I think you need to assign the time to a variable just before you enter the loop like this for example `t_0 <- Sys.time()` and then you can use the condition `Sys.time() < t_0 + 5`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!